# High CPU usage in my digitalocean droplet

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cpu-usage

I am experiencing high CPU usage here is the stats i got from server, the consumption after every restart in 15 minutes go upto 100%, what could go wrong?

I have a wordpress copy installed on the server which does not have much traffic, here is the stats that i got from using top command in server.

```
top - 11:46:02 up 12 min,  3 users,  load average: 40.89, 16.03, 6.11
Tasks: 132 total,  41 running,  91 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 24.3%us, 61.5%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  4.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 10.2%st
Mem:   2050896k total,  1988656k used,    62240k free,      284k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,     4712k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
   31 root      20   0     0    0    0 R   39  0.0   1:35.53 kswapd0
  899 root      20   0 15988  172    0 S   14  0.0   0:05.00 irqbalance
  418 syslog    20   0  243m  600    0 S   13  0.0   0:06.85 rsyslogd
  944 mysql     20   0 1320m  53m    0 S   12  2.7   0:21.15 mysqld
 2357 root      20   0 17344  532  164 R   11  0.0   0:14.27 top
  960 root      20   0  246m 3816    0 S    3  0.2   0:08.18 php5-fpm
 2431 www-data  20   0  344m  64m  908 R    2  3.2   0:04.23 apache2
 2435 www-data  20   0  304m  63m  836 R    2  3.2   0:03.43 apache2
 2413 www-data  20   0  349m  63m  920 R    2  3.2   0:07.51 apache2
 2465 www-data  20   0  349m  64m  944 R    2  3.2   0:05.04 apache2
 2518 www-data  20   0  307m  41m 1204 R    2  2.1   0:01.37 apache2
 2406 www-data  20   0  346m  56m 1144 R    2  2.8   0:03.76 apache2
 2456 www-data  20   0  345m  55m 1184 R    2  2.8   0:02.67 apache2
 2373 www-data  20   0  351m  63m  784 R    2  3.2   0:11.09 apache2
 2439 www-data  20   0  306m  35m  916 R    2  1.8   0:02.51 apache2
 2450 www-data  20   0  345m  55m 1088 R    2  2.8   0:02.96 apache2
 2486 www-data  20   0  299m  10m  876 R    2  0.5   0:01.19 apache2
 2523 www-data  20   0  300m  27m  796 R    2  1.4   0:00.99 apache2
```

Comment: It might help to run top as the CPU usage goes up to 100%

Comment: I do not get access to SSH when the CPU is running at 100%

Comment: You can set up a cronjob to run top periodically throughout the day, it might catch in action.

Comment: Your `top` output seems to be pointing at resource exhaustion. Allocate some swap space when you can access your server again. `kswapd` is known to cause lock-ups when there's no swap available and your memory is being exhausted (which is common under apache/mysql, by the way).

Comment: How do i allocate the swap space?

Comment: Assuming 12.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: A low traffic WordPress site ought to run in a 512MB droplet with room to spare. But you have a 2GB droplet and have run out of memory! So I think some service on the system isn't tuned properly and is using too much memory. Hit shift-M while running top to see what is using the most memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `top` output, it is pretty clear that you need more RAM or more swap for the workload you are running.

The way I reach this conclusion is from the following:

- The amount of free swap is exactly 0k
- The CPU usage of `kswapd` is high
- The amount of free memory, buffers, and cached are all fairly low.

When those conditions are present I have always seen performance improvement by adding a swap file or swap partition. A swap file can be created in a few simple steps. For example you could use these commands:

```
mkdir -m 700 /var/local/swapfiles
head -c100M /dev/zero > /var/local/swapfiles/1
mkswap /var/local/swapfiles/1
swapon /var/local/swapfiles/1
```

You can create another larger swap file afterwards. Initializing a big swap file when `kswapd` is acting up, can be pretty slow.

Having some swap is a good idea on most systems, and you currently have none. If you manage to fill up a GB of swap or more, then it might be you need to reduce memory consumption or add more RAM.

In `top` you can press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to see processes ordered by resident memory pages. That can give a hint about what is using your memory.